# Cant connect to https minio container from laravel container

Tags: laravel, docker, curl, https, minio

I have a laravel application running which tries to upload files to a local minio server which runs on https on port 9001.
This happens on a server with a public domain name we shall call foo.bar.com.
In the host machine (outside my docker containers) if I do `curl -k https://foo.bar.com:9001` or `curl -k https://0.0.0.0:9001` it works, but if I try to run these commands inside my laravel container I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9001: Connection refused`.

In the container I can do connect to my minio server by using the minio containers name since they are on the same network `curl -k https://pan.api.minio:9001`.

I wanted to use this but then running migrations in laravel fails with `Error executing "PutObject" on "https://pan.api.minio:9001/pan-local/ab7d6e69-5e13-4582-8855-669dcb935591/OVVzTEZiOGhSR3J1MkVHSmlIa3VoSXNsTFdJVnNWWlNCb0U2dnlsWm13dmNGUjRvWlVIVVJRTWxqak1reVhMUm1hbmV0LTItMQ%3D%3D"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'pan.api.minio' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

I just want to upload files to my minio server from within my laravel container, but why can't I connect to it by doing foo.bar.com:9001 like I can outside of my docker containers?